# Python Data extraction fails

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, read.csv

Hi I was trying to parse the complex csv.
Below is the sample csv:

```
start/stop,read/write,address,data
 Start,,,
, Write,,
,,22,
,,,0
 Start repeat,,,
, Read,,
,,22,
,,, E8
,,,22
 Stop,,,
```

I want the output achieved like below fromt the above sample csv:

```
{
    'Start': {
        'Write': {
            'Address': ['22'],
            'Data': ['0']
        },
        'Read': {
            'Address': ['22'],
            'Data': ['E8', '22']
        }
    },
    'Start repeat': {
        'Read': {
            'Address': ['22'],
            'Data': []
        }
    }
}
```

Logic tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

def extract_start_stop_lines(input_csv_path, output_txt_path):
    # Read the original CSV file into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_csv(input_csv_path)

    # Extract the desired columns
    selected_columns = ['start/stop', 'read/write', 'address', 'data']
    selected_data = df[selected_columns]

    # Display header information
    header = selected_data.columns.tolist()
    print("Header:", header)

    # Write header information to the output text file
    with open(output_txt_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outputfile:
        outputfile.write(f"Header: {', '.join(header)}\n")

        # Iterate through rows in the DataFrame
        for _, row in selected_data.iterrows():
            # Extract relevant information
            start_stop_value = str(row['start/stop']).strip() if pd.notna(row['start/stop']) else None
            operation = str(row['read/write']).strip() if pd.notna(row['read/write']) else None
            address = str(row['address']).strip() if pd.notna(row['address']) else None
            data = str(row['data']).strip() if pd.notna(row['data']) else None

            # Display extracted information
            print(f"Start/Stop: {start_stop_value}, Operation: {operation}, Address: {address}, Data: {data}")

            # Write the information to the output text file
            outputfile.write(f"Start/Stop: {start_stop_value}, Operation: {operation}, Address: {address}, Data: {data}\n")

# Example usage:
input_csv_path = 'C:\\Test\\test.csv'
output_txt_path = 'start_stop_lines.txt'
extract_start_stop_lines(input_csv_path, output_txt_path)
```

After the above code new text file will be generated here are the sample lines of files:

```
Header: start/stop, read/write, address, data
Start/Stop: Start, Operation: None, Address: None, Data: None
Start/Stop: None, Operation: Write, Address: None, Data: None
Start/Stop: None, Operation: None, Address: 22, Data: None
Start/Stop: None, Operation: None, Address: None, Data: 0
Start/Stop: Start repeat, Operation: None, Address: None, Data: None
Start/Stop: None, Operation: Read, Address: None, Data: None
Start/Stop: None, Operation: None, Address: 22, Data: None
Start/Stop: None, Operation: None, Address: None, Data: E8
Start/Stop: None, Operation: None, Address: None, Data: 22
Start/Stop: Stop, Operation: None, Address: None, Data: None
Start/Stop: Start, Operation: None, Address: None, Data: None
Start/Stop: None, Operation: Write, Address: None, Data: None
Start/Stop: None, Operation: None, Address: 22, Data: None
Start/Stop: None, Operation: None, Address: None, Data: 2
Start/Stop: None, Operation: None, Address: None, Data: FF
Start/Stop: None, Operation: None, Address: None, Data: FF
Start/Stop: Stop, Operation: None, Address: None, Data: None
```

Usually what i want to achieve here is whenever there is "Start" then find its operation whether it is "Write" or "Read" and its address and then its data values.

Pls help.

Comment: Please help i am stuck unable to find the desired dictionary values.

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error? Show FULL error message in question (not in comments) as text (not image). Don't expect that we will run code to see error. Besides code may work correctly on our computers.

Comment: I would load line by line and count `,` before text to recognize what element is in line. And I would build `dict` directly in loop (instead of writing in file) - so I could print it in every loop

Answer (score 0):

given the following input.csv

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
 Start,,,
, Write,,
,,22,
,,,0
 Start repeat,,,
, Read,,
,,22,
,,, E8
,,,22
 Stop,,,
```

you can get the following results

```
{
    "start": {
        "write": {
            "address": [
                "22"
            ],
            "data": [
                "0"
            ]
        }
    },
    "start repeat": {
        "read": {
            "address": [
                "22"
            ],
            "data": [
                "e8",
                "22"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

using the following code

```
import json

with open('input.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_rows = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]

csv_rows_without_header = csv_rows[1:]

mydict = {}

for x in range(len(csv_rows_without_header)):
    col1 = csv_rows_without_header[x].split(',')[0].strip().lower()
    col2 = csv_rows_without_header[x].split(',')[1].strip().lower()
    col3 = csv_rows_without_header[x].split(',')[2].strip().lower()
    col4 = csv_rows_without_header[x].split(',')[3].strip().lower()
    if 'start' in col1:
        mydict[col1] = {}
        temp_counter = x+1
        last_col2 = None
        try:
            while 'start' not in csv_rows_without_header[temp_counter].split(',')[0].strip().lower():
                subcol1 = csv_rows_without_header[temp_counter].split(',')[0].strip().lower()
                subcol2 = csv_rows_without_header[temp_counter].split(',')[1].strip().lower()
                subcol3 = csv_rows_without_header[temp_counter].split(',')[2].strip().lower()
                subcol4 = csv_rows_without_header[temp_counter].split(',')[3].strip().lower()
                if subcol2 != '':
                    last_col2 = subcol2[:]
                    mydict[col1][last_col2] = {}
                    mydict[col1][last_col2]['address'] = []
                    mydict[col1][last_col2]['data'] = []
                if subcol3 != '':
                    mydict[col1][last_col2]['address'].append(subcol3)
                if subcol4 != '':
                    mydict[col1][last_col2]['data'].append(subcol4)
                temp_counter = temp_counter + 1
        except IndexError:
            pass
pretty_json = json.dumps(mydict, indent=4)
print(pretty_json)
```